# How to display a "stop" icon when recording is started in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm working on a Flutter app and I have a feature where users can record audio. I want to display a "stop" icon when the recording is started, but I'm facing some difficulties in implementing this.

I have a FloatingActionButton that triggers the recording functionality, and I want to dynamically change the icon based on the recording state. The isRecording variable is updated correctly, and I have verified that the recording system itself works properly (the generated audio file is valid).

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
// ... (code snippet)

void toggleRecording() async {
  if (isRecording) {
    await record.stop();
  } else {
    if (await record.hasPermission()) {
      Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      String destinationPath = '${directory.path}/Imitations/${widget.recording.name}/${phrase.pathsToImitation.length}.m4a';
      Directory subDirectory1 = Directory('${directory.path}/Imitations');
      if (!await subDirectory1.exists()) {
        await subDirectory1.create(recursive: true);
      }
      Directory subDirectory2 = Directory('${directory.path}/Imitations/${widget.recording.name}');
      if (!await subDirectory2.exists()) {
        await subDirectory2.create(recursive: true);
      }
      await record.start(
        path: destinationPath,
        encoder: AudioEncoder.aacLc,
        bitRate: 128000,
        samplingRate: 44100,
      );
    }
  }
  setState(() {
    isRecording = !isRecording;
    print(isRecording);
  });
}

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    // ... (code snippet)
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: toggleRecording,
      child: isRecording ? const Icon(Icons.stop) : const Icon(Icons.mic),
    ),
  );
}

// ... (code snippet)
```

I want the FloatingActionButton to display a "stop" icon (Icons.stop) when the recording is started (isRecording = true), and a microphone icon (Icons.mic) when the recording is stopped (isRecording = false).

The isRecording variable and recording is correctly updated, and I have verified this by checking the generated audio file. However, the icon doesn't change dynamically based on the isRecording variable.

I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to achieve this functionality. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Which package have you used ?

Comment: And how you decide that recording is ended without any intervention to app?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I use the package 'record: ^4.4.4.' https://pub.dev/packages/record

Comment: Also please answer the above question

Comment: I use print(isRecording) to verify that isRecording becomes true when I pressed the FAB and when I do so again it becomes false. I've also verified that there is a saved recording file in the app directory.

Comment: Okay so you it goes like this 1)tap on mic button and record audio. 2)Then again tap on same button and stop recording and file saved .but still there is a stop icon rather then mic icon

Comment: Actually, the mic icon (not the stop icon) is displayed all the time and does not change though the recording is performed correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254525/discussion-between-akshay-gupta-and-).

Answer (score 1):

Yes but note that stateful builder have there own setstate so if you want to update ui which resides in stateful builder you have to use it's setstate not the actually class setstate .both are different